# Audio does not play in Jar but does in eclipse

Tags: java, audio, jar, javasound, clip

Sound does not play when I run the JAR, but it does when I run it in eclipse.

Here is where I load the clips:

```
public void init(){
    System.out.println("grabbing Music");
    String currentDir = new File("").getAbsolutePath();
    name=new File(currentDir+"\\music\\").list();
    clip=new Clip[name.length];
    soundFile=new File[name.length];
    for(int x=0;x<name.length;x++){
        System.out.println(currentDir+"\\music\\"+name[x]);
        try {
            soundFile[x]= new File(currentDir+"\\music\\"+name[x]);
            AudioInputStream sound = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(soundFile[x]);
            DataLine.Info info= new DataLine.Info(Clip.class, sound.getFormat());
            clip[x] = (Clip) AudioSystem.getLine(info);
            clip[x].open(sound);
            clip[x].addLineListener(new LineListener(){
                public void update(LineEvent event) {
                    if (event.getType() == LineEvent.Type.STOP) {
                        event.getLine().close();
                    }
                }
            });
        } catch (LineUnavailableException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (UnsupportedAudioFileException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

I do not get any errors when running it in Eclipse.  There should be no possibility of an invalid directory error, so what is wrong?

-When the jar is run in CMD i get no errors.

edit: I feel like I am loading the audio wrong, hence why I pasted the code I used to load the files in. In my searches I haven't seen anyone use File to load in a sound file. Wonder if that is the problem?

Comment: Print the stack trace please.

Comment: no errors are thrown. It just doesnt play.

Comment: how you are checking the error?

Comment: running it through cmd does not throw anything nor print any stacktraces.

Answer (score 1):

First thing that goes into my mind is that you didn't attached your sound library classes into your jar.

Comment: Sorry but I am new to java and dont really understand what you mean by "attached your sound library classes into your jar" shouldnt that be done by eclipse automatically? + no errors are thrown, if the errors were thrown i would have seen them in the CMD.

Answer (score 1):

In order to run your current code, the folder `music` should be in the same folder the jar file is located in.

Another solution is to package your `music` folder inside the jar file and then change your code to:

```
InputStream is = getClass().getResourceAsStream("/music/" + name[x]);
AudioInputStream sound = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(is);
```

Comment: the folder is in the same directory as my jar file. I will try the code you suggested. hopefully it works!

Comment: When i use your code it does not work. Throws IOExeception: Mark/reset not supported

Answer (score 1):

How about-

1. Right click on your project in Eclipse. Then New -> Source Folder.
2. Name the source folder anything. e.g. music_src.
3. Copy or drag the entire music directory in music_src. Then make the jar.

Answer (score 0):

File systems have a hard time looking into jars. 
Try using URL instead. A URL can locate a location within a jar. This happens a lot with folks trying to access resources in jars for the first time.
Otherwise things look fine.